# Setting sort in onLazyLoad event triggers infinity loop on p-table

Tags: angular, primeng, p-table

I'm new to Angular and getting a Issue at the PrimeNG p-table.

This is my `p-table`

```
<p-table [value]="data" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)" [multiSortMeta]="sort" .... >
```

When anything changes I come in my `loadData` Method.

```
loadData(event): void {

    this.dataservice.loadData(..fields from event...).subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result.data;
        this.sort = result.sort; // <- This run into infinity loop
    })
}
```

So everytime I change `this.sort` I am coming into my loadData which will again do a request and so on.

Comment: I have the same issue, any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I set an array variable and re-assign it.

**WRONG IMPLEMENTATION**

**sample.html**

```
<p-table [value]="data" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)" sortMode="multiple"[multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta">
```

**sample.ts**

```
public multiSortMeta: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadData();
}

loadData(event: any) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (event.multiSortMeta !== undefined && event.multiSortMeta.length > 0) {
      const reference = [...this.multiSortMeta];
      event.multiSortMeta.map((sort) => {
        const sortIndex = reference.findIndex((f: any) => { return f.field === sort.field; });
        if (sortIndex > -1) {
          reference[sortIndex].order = sort.order;
        } else {
          reference.push({ field: sort.field, order: sort.order, requireReload: true });
        }
      });
      this.multiSortMeta = [...reference]; // It cause for infinite loop
    }
    this.someService.search(this.params, this.multiSortMeta)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }, 0);
}
```

**CORRECT IMPLEMENTATION**

Here I added a flag (`requireReload`) to check whether to reload data or not. Once a function is called we set a flag to `true` to reload and once it's done then set it back to `false`, So another time function executes then it will doesn't reload and it breaks the loop.

**sample.html** NO CHANGE REQUIRED

```
<p-table [value]="data" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)" sortMode="multiple"[multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta">
```

**sample.ts**

```
public multiSortMeta: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadData();
}

loadData(event: any) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // For multiple sorting
    if (event.multiSortMeta !== undefined && event.multiSortMeta.length > 0) {
      event.multiSortMeta.map((sort) => {
        const sortIndex = this.multiSortMeta.findIndex((f: any) => { return f.field === sort.field; });
        if (sortIndex > -1) {
          // When sort change
          if (this.multiSortMeta[sortIndex].order !== sort.order) {
            this.multiSortMeta[sortIndex].requireReload = true // We set a flag here to reload the data
          }
          this.multiSortMeta[sortIndex].order = sort.order;
        } else {
          // When new sort column added
          this.multiSortMeta.push({ field: sort.field, order: sort.order, requireReload: true });
        }
      });

      // Check if any of key require reload
      const requireReload = this.multiSortMeta.some((m: any) => {
        return m.requireReload;
      });

      // It will reload only when a new sort column is added or the previous one is altered
      if (requireReload) {
        this.multiSortMeta.forEach((m: any) => {
          return m.requireReload = false; // Here we false to reload so next time it will not be called and It brakes the infinite loop
        });
        this.multiSortMeta = [...this.multiSortMeta];
        this.loadService();
      }
    } else {
      // For normal pagination and stuff
      this.loadService();
    }
  }, 0);
}

loadService() {
  this.someService.search(this.params, this.multiSortMeta)
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great example and it works flawlessly! Thanks again for sharing it.